# How to replace five digits from a string?

Tags: c#, regex

How to replace five digits from a string?
Possibly a solution in Regexes, my regular expression skills are not so strong.

```
string ort = "42671 VÄSTRA FRÖLUNDA";
```

Comment: More details, which ones do you want to replace?  What with?

Comment: If you are looking for replacing digits from the beginning of string this is the rgex you need: "^\d+"

Answer (score 2):

```
    String result = Regex.Replace("input string",@"\d{5}",ReplaceFiveDigits);

    private static string ReplaceFiveDigits(Match m)
    {
        return "VALUE TO REPLACE";
    }
```

Comment: You need a 3rd argument for the replacement string (or `MatchEvaluator` delegate).

Answer (score 1):

`\d{5}` will match five digits anywhere in a string. This can be used with `Regex.Replace`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var replaced = Regex.Replace(ort, @"\d{5}", "REPLACE WITH THIS");
```

will replace any 5 consecutive digits.

do you also want to remove the space afterwards?

```
var replaced = Regex.Replace(ort, @"\d{5}\s?", "REPLACE WITH THIS");
```